# Ability to use ajax again when Ajax's success is true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how do i want to redirect to another page using ajax again in if if a data with ajax is true and get that data there

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'giris.php',
            type : 'post',
            data : {kullanici_adi : kullanici_adi , sifre : sifre},
            success : function(e){
                if(e==true){
                    alert("Giriş Yapılıyor");
                    $.ajax({
                        url : 'learn.html',
                        type : 'post',
                        data : {kullanici_adi : kullanici_adi}
                    });
                    $(location).attr('href', 'learn.html');

                }
            }

    });
```

learn.html

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['kullanici_adi'])){
        echo $_POST['kullanici_adi'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, it doesn't seem like you need the if statement inside the success. Try running it without that. What happens?

Comment: I need no because the other page will return false and true values ​​so no need ajax work when it returns false